# Correct VS 2017 jsDoc intellisense syntax for object function declarations

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2017, jsdoc

I can't figure out how to get a jsDoc format working that will make VS2017 show the correct information in intellisense.

```
//seems like you can use several different formats to get 
// 'this is a test' to appear in intellisense
// and the @param data to appear as well
/**
 * this is a test 
 * @param {string} myConstructorParm - constructor parm, can be anything.
 */ 
function myObject(myConstructorParm) {

    this.localParm = myConstructorParm;

    //this doesn't do anything
    /** setLocalParm - sets value of localParm, overwrites constructor value.
    * @param { string } newValue - the new value to be assigned into localParm 
    */
    this.setLocalParm = function (newValue) { this.localParm = newValue; }
}
```

As seen above, defining a new object and giving THAT jsDoc info works fine.  But as the question tile suggests, I can't get the syntax (if it is even possible) for any of the properties I defined to work (i.e. to show up in intellisense).  All that shows up is VS basic intellisense and none of my text.

So, am I doing something wrong, or is VS just not supporting this yet?  I know certain jsDoc features are not working yet... so really my question is CAN you get this to work with what currently IS supported in VS2017?

Comment: You have a typo... a JSDoc comment begins with two `*`. Finally, capitalize constructor function names! Please!

Comment: @AluanHaddad Actually, `setLocalParam` is a method, not a property, and the function takes a parameter, so @param is wholly appropriate. You are correct on the two asterisks.

Comment: Well you are right, technically it is property that is a function that has a parameter.

Comment: The list of supported jsDoc tags is listed here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JsDoc-support-in-JavaScript

Comment: Not sure how this is off topic.

Comment: OK.  I fixed the typos.  As for 'supported jsDoc tags' comment, I already addressed the fact I am aware of limited support AND I stated I wanted to know if anybody knows how to get the SUPPORTED tags to do what I need...I have tried dozens of formats.  The typo was not present in my local test code.  Also, VS 'intellisense' identifies setLocalParameter as a property.

Comment: @AustinRhymer you can definitely annotate the parameter on the right hand side of the `=`.